# is it possible to use pure node js without using express as a back-end for vue js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I've already created a project using **vue js** and **node js** but with express. I was just thinking if it's possible to use **node js** alone without using such a framework?

Comment: Yes. It's possible.

Comment: What is the point of throwing away a perfectly working module?  Are you just really excited to rewrite a lot of code for yourself that already exists in a proven module?  Or does it not do something you need it to do?  Or why?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to develop a whole website/web app without an extra framework like express. The thing is that you have to manage so many things on your own.

Your web app/website code became harder to read as you progress in NodeJS. URL routing is complex than express. So, You have to write a bunch of switch cases.

It's possible to use NodeJS alone. But, you have to write more code that is provided by express or any other framework.